# Prevent AWTEventMulticaster from being put on stack

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am implementing a chess board and when I click a point on the board the MousePressed Event fires twice. I checked the stack and I see that AWTEVENTMulticaster is on top of the stack. I am not sure how to handle this and prevent the mousepressed event from being called more than once.

Code:

```
public static JPanel[][] pnlCells = new JPanel[8][8];
public boolean firstClick = false;
public boolean secondClick = false;
public void test(){
     for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            final int tempi = i;
            final int tempj = j;
            pnlCells[i][j].add(getPieceObject(str[(7 - i)][j]), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pnlCells[i][j].validate();
            pnlCells[i][j].addMouseListener(ml); 
        }
     }
}

MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        try {
            if (firstClick == false || secondClick == false) {
                JPanel source = (JPanel)e.getSource();
                int tempi = 0;
                int tempj = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < pnlCells.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < pnlCells[i].length; j++) {
                        if (pnlCells[i][j] == source) {
                            tempi = i;
                            tempj = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                    if (firstClick == false) {                           
                        mouseX = tempj;
                        mouseY = 7 - tempi;
                        System.out.println("First You pressed" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
                        firstClick = true;
                        sourceColor = pnlCells[mouseX][mouseY].getForeground();
                        pnlCells[mouseX][mouseY].setForeground(Color.yellow);
                        pnlCells[mouseX][mouseY].repaint();
                        pnlBoard.repaint();
                        pnlMain.repaint();
                    } else if (secondClick == false) {
                        newMouseX = tempj;
                        newMouseY = 7 - tempi;
                        System.out.println("Second You pressed" + newMouseX + ", " + newMouseY);
                        secondClick = true;
                    } 


                    if (firstClick == true && secondClick == true) {
                        firstClick = false;
                        secondClick = false;
                        pnlCells[mouseX][mouseY].setForeground(sourceColor);
                        pnlCells[mouseX][mouseY].repaint();
                        pnlBoard.repaint();
                        pnlMain.repaint();

                        PlayerMove pM = turn(); //send turn to server
                        objectOut.writeObject(pM); //send turn to server
                        System.out.println(name + ": sent move to server");
                        s.suspend();
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e
    ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e
    ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e
    ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e
    ) {

    }
};
```

I have no other mousepressed anywhere else.

Comment: It's more likely the `MosueListener` has been registered more then once.  The use of `static` here `public static JPanel[][] pnlCells = new JPanel[8][8];` would be my first concern. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Once I wrapped runnable code around your `test` method and `MouseListener`, it worked just fine for me.  First click triggered "first" path, second click triggered "second" and "move" passes...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will try post what I have because I always get the "First You Pressed""Second You Pressed" printed out

Comment: BTW - why not swap the panel + mouse listener for a (possibly undecorated) button + action listener?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I could try to find out how to do that

Comment: @AndrewThompson How would I register a JBUTTON array to a actionlistener only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed everything to use JButtons and ActionListeners, however I had same problem. But then I checked for the amount of listeners already on the jbutton array and everything worked.

```
if(pnlCells[i][j].getActionListeners().length < 1){
    pnlCells[i][j].addActionListener(ml);
}
```